# How to programmatically detect that Wi-Fi is public

Tags: python, network-programming

A colleague told me that devices will sometimes spoof their MAC address if they detect that they are on a public Wi-Fi hotspot. Now, how is this possible?

Question: How can you programmatically tell (say by running a Python script on a Mac) that the internet connection you're currently on is through a public access point (e.g. a cafe)?

Thinking outside the box: For example, is there a web service that provides this information or similar? I've installed fing, which will tell me the MAC addresses of devices on my local network. So a related question is: is there a way to tell apart MAC address that are spoofed, e.g. for iPhones, from those that are not spoofed (thinking separate MAC address spaces or something)? If yes, the presence of spoofed iphone MAC addresses could indicate a public access Wi-Fi, even if I don't know how Apple does that.

Comment: do you mean public as in open?

Comment: Detecting if a wifi is public is not an easy task as there can be many false positives. One can assume if there is no password required to authenticate a wifi network then it could be a open or public network. could be a honeypot too. Usually public wifi networks have passwords to authenticate now a days. So one idea would be to get the SSID name and then try to match it with the common SSID's of public WiFi. For eg: Starbucks, MCDonalds etc. This is not very efficient.

Comment: Here is a good article: http://www.collegetimes.tv/change-mac-address/
Spoofing MAC with python can be done with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpoofMAC/ or you can develop your own script

Comment: The OUI may help to determine if the mac is being spoofed presuming it has been changed

Comment: If you have the original MAC of a device. Then connect this device to a network and assuming that this device will spoof its MAC if the wifi is public. Then try to compare the current MAC of the device with the original one. If they are different then you may assume that the wifi is public. Just a thought. :) Getting MAC of a device is not difficult in python.